# how to configure apache tiles to read jsps from inside jar files?

Tags: apache, configuration, tiles

The architecture of my web application is highly modular. I am using apache tiles as the templating framework. The app modules are bundled as different jar files and put inside WEB-INF/lib folder. So each jar file will contain its own tiles configuration files (containing tiles definitions) and related jsp templates.

I am using CompleteAutoloadTilesListener which is a part of tiles-extras package to read the tiles config files from the jar files. But the jsp files aren't picked up by tiles. When I access any definition, it couldn't find the jsp template file.

A configuration change will solve this problem? or should I subclass any tiles base class to let tiles load jsps from the jar?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Are you using Spring-MVC?

Comment: I don't have much reputation, so offering just +50. :)

Comment: Hello. Have you solved this problem? I have the same now(

Answer (score 0):

Someone else ran into this problem before and even [wrote a blog about it](http://richardbarabe.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/apache-tiles-2-integration-with-spring-mvc/)

It mentions [this issue](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5411) that is fixed, so you should be able to use the same setup and load your tiles definitions from the classpath.

I haven't tested it, but it looks like a sensible solution.